# How do I fix the "No known features for CXX compiler" while compiling with CMake (Linux Mint)

Tags: c++, cmake, linux-mint

I am trying to install this plugin: https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink

I followed all the steps (Installed QT, got obs-studio source code and then tried to build the plugin):

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev

git clone --recursive https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git

git clone https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink.git
cd obs-v4l2sink
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DLIBOBS_INCLUDE_DIR="../../obs-studio/libobs" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

But then...

```
 -- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No known features for CXX compiler

  ""

  version .


-- Build files have been written to: /home/********/obs-v4l2sink/build
```

It is my first time compiling using `cmake` (instead of `make`), and I don't know much about compiling. Was there any step I missed between installing `cmake` and trying to compile the plugin?

From what I found online, here's what I have done:

- `build-essential` is already installed;
- `c++`, `cc` and all are installed as well;
- tried to add `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc` to the `cmake` command line (did the same with c++);

And of course, I have done the `update && upgrade`

Here's what's in the CMakeError.log file :

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut pas trouver Scrt1.o : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut pas trouver crti.o : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/***********/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_f18b2/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/build
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/***********/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp »
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/***********/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_f18b2
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_f18b2 
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut pas trouver Scrt1.o : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut pas trouver crti.o : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_f18b2.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_f18b2' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_f18b2] Error 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/***********/obs-v4l2sink/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp »
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_f18b2/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_f18b2/fast] Error 2


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! One clarification, CMake doesn't do any compiling. CMake will generate the build system (e.g. generates the Makefiles), then after running CMake, you can use `make` or some other command to initiate compilation.

Comment: Also, the fact that CMake is looking for compiler features, but it can no longer print the compiler to the screen (`""`) makes me think there is something wrong with your configuration, perhaps caused by trial-and-error when you were setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. Try deleting the `build` folder, repeating this step `mkdir build && cd build`, and all the steps after it. That will clear any old/stale CMake cache.. hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you! It did work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

The error message is peculiar. It looks like CMake previously detected a C++ compiler, and is searching for compiler features for it. However, now it cannot find that compiler (blank compiler name and version):

> ```
> CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>   No known features for CXX compiler
>
>   ""
>
>   version .
> ```

This is indicative of a stale CMake configuration, and it may be useful to clean it up. Try removing the `build` folder altogether, and run the CMake steps again from the tutorial (starting from creation of the `build` folder as shown below). This will help clear out the old/cached CMake settings:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DLIBOBS_INCLUDE_DIR="../../obs-studio/libobs" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Comment: I have the same output for googletest and deleting the `cmake-build-debug` directory and reloading the project didn't help.

Comment: @JinKwon Note, in the tutorial, the directory name is simply `build`, so perhaps you are deleting the wrong directory.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sharing my problem.

I got the same message as soon as I applied [Quickstart: Building with CMake](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)
.

The problem was the [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command which specified `LANGUAGES` element.

```
project(my-project C)
```

I removed the `C` part and it works now.

```
project(my-project)
```

Specifying both languages seems to work.

```
project(my-project LANGUAGES C CXX)
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to visual studio downloads and download tools regarding visual studio and it will works.
2. I spend nearly 3 days for this (I reinstall the vscode 2022 eventhough it's not worked).
3. My Superior suggest me to download tools for visual studio and check  ,

now it's working.

Comment: He's not using Visual Studio. His compiler is /usr/bin/cc.

Comment: I don't no about others how they resolve but above 3 steps resolved my problem and now i am running the code.