# No known features for CUDA compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

What is the real meaning of this error? I.e. putting aside the obvious problem where cmake is printing a bad error message because some variables are empty, what variables is it expecting to not be empty?

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No known features for CUDA compiler

  ""

  version .
```

I'm assuming this is a core cmake message because I can't find the error strings and similar output exists for "CXX" ([How do I fix the "No known features for CXX compiler" while compiling with CMake (Linux Mint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416987/how-do-i-fix-the-no-known-features-for-cxx-compiler-while-compiling-with-cmake)) with similarly vague answers about a stale build directory.

My minimum working example is...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test_project)

set(USE_CUGRAPH_OPS OFF)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/share/nccl")
add_subdirectory(cugraph/cpp)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

add_executable(test
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE
    CUDA::cudart
    cugraph
)
```

```bash
# install https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/nccl/secure/2.18.5/agnostic/aarch64sbsa/nccl_2.18.5-1+cuda12.2_aarch64.txz to /usr/local/share/nccl

git clone git@github.com:rapidsai/cugraph.git
cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Things compile smoothly after removing the target_link_libraries `cugraph` dependency. While the error may be related to something cugraph is doing, this question is specifically about following a line of investigation from the cmake error message.

Comment: Not sure what kind of a subproject you have under `cugraph/cpp`, but probably it expects CUDA language to be enabled.  You could try to add something like `enable_language(CUDA)` before `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Bizarre error message from missing [enable_language()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html) though.

Comment: Funny, but it is the very same approach as in the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69293851/3440745) to the referenced question: adding the specification of the language noted in the error message. Despite to the similar solution, currently I am not sure about duplicates. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I had tried adding CXX and CUDA to `project()` which had uncovered `Target "raft_lib" requires the language dialect "CUDA23"...`. Turns out that was due to `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)` set elsewhere but it was enough to make me think this problem was different. `enable_language()` is better because the root project shouldn't need to know if dependencies happen to use CUDA or not. Happy to close as a dupe. At least google has a "CUDA" version of it now.